# How to manipulate individual input field values without a lot of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote some code using jQuery to convert `<input>` field values from one unit system to another (English <-> Metric).  All was going well until I have realized that I am using a class selector, so instead of each value doing its conversion individually, all values (with same class) get converted to the same identical value (equal to the first occurrence of `class`).

An obvious solution is to assign an `id` to each value, which I suppose will work, but I am here to ask if there is a better way.  I have a lot of values (which is why I tried using class), and would like to avoid using `id`, if possible.  But, all I am looking for is "convert each value individually (using my conversion function)".  How can this be done?

**jQuery**

```
function convertValues() {
    if ($('#unit_system').val() == "English") //if changed to English
    {
        $('.value_gpm').val(    //do converstion from Metric to English
            convert($('.value_gpm').val(), "m3h", "gpm")
         );
    }
    else if ($('#unit_system').val() == "Metric") //if changed to Metric
    {
        $('.value_gpm').val(    //do conversion from English to Metric
            convert($('.value_gpm').val(), "gpm", "m3h")
         );
    }
}
```

**Calling Function**

```
//below code is for select box (HTML for it is not shown)
$("#unit_system").change(function(){ //select box change detected
    convertValues();    //function is called
});
```

**HTML at first** (before Select box change)

```
<input type="text" class="value_gpm" name="design_a" value="444" />
<input type="text" class="value_gpm" name="design_b" value="555" />
<input type="text" class="value_gpm" name="design_c" value="666" />
<input type="text" class="value_gpm" name="design_d" value="777" />
<input type="text" class="value_gpm" name="design_e" value="888" />
```

**HTML after** (after Select box is changed)

```
<input type="text" class="value_gpm" name="design_a" value="1954.87" />
<input type="text" class="value_gpm" name="design_b" value="1954.87" />
<input type="text" class="value_gpm" name="design_c" value="1954.87" />
<input type="text" class="value_gpm" name="design_d" value="1954.87" />
<input type="text" class="value_gpm" name="design_e" value="1954.87" />
```

Expected behavior:  conversion produces different value per row

Actual behavior:  same value produced for each row

Comment: And how are you calling this function? What's the (relevant) HTML? Where are the buttons that are being clicked, or inputs that are being changed or selected?

Comment: I don't understand at all, but you can use the name attribute to find each element $('input[name=design_a]').val().....

Comment: if you want, you can use element array. `document.getElementsByCaalssName('value_gpm')[0]` will give you the first element or `document.getElementsByCaalssName('value_gpm')[1]` will give you the second input. This will work only if you know the element order exactly. jQuery way is `$('value_gpm')[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through them, something like this.

```
var inputs = $('.value_gpm');

for(i=0;i < inputs.length; i++){
 var input = inputs[i];

 input.val( convert(input.val(), "m3h", "gpm") );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best bet - using [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and [`$(this)`](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var valueEls = $('.value_gpm');       

    $("#unit_system").change(function(){
        var unit = $(this).val();

        switch(unit){
            case "English":
            valueEls.each(function(){
                $(this).val(convert($(this).val(), "m3h", "gpm");
            });
            break;
            case "Metric":
            valueEls.each(function(){
                $(this).val(convert($(this).val(), "gpm", "m3h");
            });
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use each()

```
$("value_gpm").each(function () {
  convert(this.val(), ...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

The less lines of codes I figure out for this is this:

```
var unit_system = $('#unit_system').val();

$('.value_gpm').each(function(){
    convert($(this).val(), unit_system == "English" ? "m3h" : "gpm", unit_system == "English" ? "gpm" : "m3h");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery each:

```
$("#unit_system").change(function(){
    var fromUnit = "m3h";
    var toUnit = "gpm";
    if ($(this).val() == "Metric"){
        fromUnit = "gpm";
        toUnit = "m3h";
    }
    $('.value_gpm').each(function(){
        $(this).val(convert($(this).val(), fromUnit, toUnit));
    });
});
```